# Creating a tokenizer using the method Split

Tags: java, design-patterns, split, token, tokenize

I'm trying to create simple tokenizer that splits on whitespace, lowercases tokens, removes all nonalphabetic characters, and keeps only terms with 3 or more characters. I write this code, it´s all ready work on lowercases, nonalphabetic characters and only keeps 3 or more characters. But I want to use the method split, but I don't know how. Please suggest something.

```
public class main {

    public static final String EXAMPLE_TEST = "This Mariana John bar Barr "
        + "12364 FFFFF aaaa a s d f g.";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\s[a-z]{3,20})");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(EXAMPLE_TEST);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.print("Start index: " + matcher.start());
            System.out.print(" End index: " + matcher.end() + " ");
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) `split` cannot lowercase result. --- 2) You can't use `split` to *"remove all nonalphabetic characters"* without also splitting on them, but you said to only *"split on whitespace"*, e.g. what should happen with input `abc1@3xyz`? Should that return `abcxyz` (nonalphabetics *removed*), or should it return `abc` and `xyz`? --- Your requirements, as stated, are impossible.

Comment: I'm also curious as to why you want to use `split()` when your regex already meets your requirements.

Comment: because I'm asked to use split ()

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have to track the index:

```
List<String> processed = Arrays.stream(EXAMPLE_TEST.split(" ")).map(String::toLowerCase)
            .map(s -> s.replaceAll("[^a-z]", "")).filter(s -> s.length() >= 3).collect(Collectors.toList());
for (String s : processed) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

But your example output presents the index as well. Then you have to store it in additional container (like Map):

```
Map<Integer, String> processed = Arrays.stream(EXAMPLE_TEST.split(" ")).collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> EXAMPLE_TEST.indexOf(s), s -> s.toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]", "")));
Map<Integer, String> filtered = processed.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getValue().length() >= 3).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : filtered.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Start index: " + entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your requirement doesn't say "max 20" anywhere, change `[a-z]{3,20}` to `[a-z]{3,}` for unlimited length.

Regex cannot lowercase the tokens, so you need to call `toLowerCase()` separately. Your regex will only work ok if you do that *before* invoking the regex. If you intend to call `toLowerCase()` on each token *after* invoking the regex, you need to change `[a-z]` to `[a-zA-Z]`. Easiest is doing it before.

The above means that your code should be modified as follows:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-z]{3,}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(EXAMPLE_TEST.toLowerCase());
```

*Output*

```
Start index: 0 End index: 4 this
Start index: 5 End index: 12 mariana
Start index: 13 End index: 17 john
Start index: 18 End index: 21 bar
Start index: 22 End index: 26 barr
Start index: 33 End index: 38 fffff
Start index: 39 End index: 43 aaaa
```

---

To do the same thing using `split`, you need to split on any sequence of characters that consists of nonalphabetic characters or at most 2 consecutive alphabetic characters.

```
String[] split = EXAMPLE_TEST.toLowerCase().split("(?:[^a-z]+|(?<![a-z])[a-z]{1,2}(?![a-z]))+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split));
```

*Output*

```
[this, mariana, john, bar, barr, fffff, aaaa]
```

Explanation:

```
(?:              Start non-capturing repeating group:
   [^a-z]+           Match one or more nonalphabetic characters
 |                 Or
   (?<![a-z])        Not preceded by an alphabetic character
   [a-z]{1,2}        Match 1-2 alphabetic characters
   (?![a-z])         Not followed by an alphabetic character
)+               Match one or more of the above
```

*Note:* The `+` after `[^a-z]` can be removed, since the `+` at the end will do the repetition anyway, but the regex should perform better with the `+` there.

The difference between the original code and the split code is that split will return an empty string as the first result if the input starts with a nonalphabetic character.